# Serial Number in SSRS Pivot Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to put a column in SSRS report with running serial number. The report is pivoted in SSRS. I tried the same with RunningValue function and RowNumber too. But still it could not generate it in the way i want.

It's generating the rownumber on raw data from which pivot is being created.

I tried all these which all are of no mean : -

=RowNumber("Row_Group_Name")

=RowNumber(Nothing)

=RunningValue(Fields!FieldName.Value, Count, Nothing)

etc.

Generated Serial Numbers : -

4

8

10

16

etc.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer: -

=RunningValue(Fields!FieldName.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing)